# Finding the bug in C program

Tags: c, debugging

I have that C program codes below. There should be a phantom bug in it that only occurs sometimes, however whenever I run it, it just works fine. I can't find where the bug is in there

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct thread_data {
char name[255];
unsigned int num_iterations;
unsigned int some_answer;
};

void* thread_entrypoint(void *arg)
{
int i;
struct thread_data *tdata = (struct thread_data*)arg;

tdata->some_answer = 0;
for (i=0; i<tdata->num_iterations; i++) {
    tdata->some_answer += i;
}

printf("Name: %s, Answer: %u\n", tdata->name, tdata->some_answer);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread_t tid;
struct thread_data tdata;

strcpy(tdata.name, "Spartacus");
tdata.num_iterations = 100;

pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_entrypoint, &tdata);
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: How do you know there is a bug? Have you used a debugger?

Comment: stack overflow is no remote debugging service. Use a debugger and tools like valgrind to track down the problem.

Comment: Also, formatting/indentation:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you pass the thread pointer to local variable from the main thread and then you leave the scope, either by exiting the main thread or returning from the function:

```
struct thread_data tdata;
```

You have to allocate this structure on the heap to make it working reliably. It basically depends whether exiting the main thread is faster than completing the child thread. It may depend on number of CPUs, current process load etc. so it's very random.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the thread `tid` to finish, before you exit the main thread, so that `tdata` remains valid and so that the process doesn't terminate before you see the output in stdout.

To do this, you should call `pthread_join(tid,...)` after the call to `pthread_create(&tid,...)` (see https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining)